# How to install an older version of an app on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I want to install an older version of WeChat on my phone.  I have IOS 12.5.7 any way to install an older version of WeChat on my phone?

As itunes is no longer supported, the answer here [How do I install an older version of an app on an iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195074/how-do-i-install-an-older-version-of-an-app-on-an-iphone)

No longer works.

Comment: @Allan this question is the same but the answer is out of date as itunes is no longer supported.

Comment: We mark *questions* as dupes, not answers.  The dupe question cited can get updated answers posted that are more up to date.

Comment: If the existing answers don’t work for you, please explain in detail what you did and where it failed to work.

Comment: Also see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/325913/119271, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332512/119271, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378336/119271, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/385196/119271, https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/90142/119271

Comment: And…. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/394098/119271   Most of those existing posts don't reference itunes

Comment: @Allan. the ones that don't reference itunes aren't solutions they're just answers of the form no you can't

Comment: “No you can’t” is a *valid* answer.  If the older version of WeChat isn’t available any more, there’s nothing you’re going to do to get it.

Comment: @Allan for other apps one can use tools like 3utools to add the app to your apple account
there's also the possibility of old IPAs and sideloading. "No you can't" just means they can't think of a way.

Comment: That may be, but it doesn’t change the fact this is a **duplicate question**.